# Youtube API & Django integration

Tags: python, django, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, infinite-loop

I have a function in Django that uses the youtube API to return the video_id, title and thumbnail_url based on the web_url that is provided by the user through the user create Video object form. The reason I did this was to make it easy for users to upload youtube videos to my app.

```
def get_video_info(pk):
    print('get_video_info called')
    video = Video.objects.get(id=pk)
    web_url = video.web_url

    # Parse the video ID from the URL
    parsed_url = urlparse(web_url)
    query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
    video_id = query_params["v"][0]

    # Create a YouTube Data API client
    api_key = settings.YOUTUBE_API_KEY
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

    # Call the YouTube API to get the video details
    video_response = youtube.videos().list(
        part='id, snippet',
        id=video_id,
        maxResults=1
    ).execute()

    # Extract the video details from the API response
    video_snippet = video_response['items'][0]['snippet']
    thumbnail_url = video_snippet['thumbnails']['medium']['url']
    title = video_snippet['title']

    return {
        'video_id': video_id,
        'thumbnail_url': thumbnail_url,
        'title': title,
    }
```

I then have a signal function that triggers the get_video_info function when a Video object is created and then updates the Video fields with the return values of the function.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def create_video_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('create signal called')
    if created: # if the instance is being created
        video_id, thumbnail_url, title = get_video_info(instance.pk).values()
        instance.video_id = video_id
        instance.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url
        instance.title = title
        instance.save()
```

my problem is that when i tried to create a similar signal for when the video object is being updated I was getting an infinite recursion loop. Any ideas on how to solve this issue would be much appreciated, thanks!

This is the previous signal i tried:

```
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Video)
def update_video_info(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('update signal called')
    if hasattr(instance, 'pk') and instance.pk:
        video_id, thumbnail_url, title = get_video_info(instance.pk).values()
        instance.video_id = video_id
        instance.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url
        instance.title = title
        instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def update_video_info(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if not created and 'web_url' in update_fields:
        print('update signal called')
        video_id, thumbnail_url, title = get_video_info(instance.pk).values()
        instance.video_id = video_id
        instance.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url
        instance.title = title
        instance.save(update_fields=['video_id', 'thumbnail_url', 'title'])
```

You can use the **update_fields** parameter of the **save()** method to specify which fields have changed and should need to be updated.